# How to remove a Warning label from Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, label, try-catch

I have some code that wants to check the validity of user input to two tk entries, if a letter is typed instead of a number it posts a warning in red text - this is performs correctly. What I would like it to do is remove the red text once the user inserts numbers - at the moment the red ValueError text remains and I would like it to vanish once the button is pressed if the two entries are numbers.

***Code***

```
print('\n'*3)
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
pw_low = 0.01
pw_high = 30.0

lab1 = tk.Label(root, text="Pulse Width Start (\u03bcS):").grid(row = 0)
start_pw = tk.StringVar()
entry1 = tk.Entry(root, width=20, textvariable = start_pw).grid(row = 0, column = 1)
start_pw.set(pw_low)

lab2 = tk.Label(root, text="Pulse Width End (\u03bcS):").grid(row = 1)
end_pw = tk.StringVar()
entry2 = tk.Entry(root, width=20, textvariable = end_pw).grid(row = 1, column = 1)
end_pw.set(pw_high)


def getPWrange():
    try:
        user_start_pw_num = float(start_pw.get())
    except ValueError:
        answer_label.config(text = 'You must enter an integer or decimal number', fg = 'red')
    try:
        user_end_pw_num = float(end_pw.get())
        user_pw_range = [user_start_pw_num, user_end_pw_num ]
        print('user_pw_range: ',user_pw_range)
    except ValueError:
        answer_label.config(text = 'You must enter an integer or decimal number', fg = 'red')


button = tk.Button(root, text="Range", command = getPWrange)
button.grid(row = 2, column = 3)
answer_label = tk.Label(root, text = '')
answer_label.grid(row = 3)

root.mainloop()
```

***Unsatisfactory solution***

Adding a label destroy using after does remove the label once a number is added BUT if a letter is entered after that the warning error does not show, instead I get a traceback

```
def getPWrange():
    try:
        user_start_pw_num = float(start_pw.get())
    except ValueError:
        answer_label.config(text = 'You must enter an integer or decimal number', fg = 'red')
        answer_label.after(2000, answer_label.destroy)
    try:
        user_end_pw_num = float(end_pw.get())
        user_pw_range = [user_start_pw_num, user_end_pw_num ]
        print('user_pw_range: ',user_pw_range)
    except ValueError:
        answer_label.config(text = 'You must enter an integer or decimal number', fg = 'red')


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.../opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/.../Desktop/tk_gui_grid/t6.py", line 24, in getPWrange
    answer_label.config(text = 'You must enter an integer or decimal number', fg = 'red')
  File "/Users/.../opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1485, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "/Users/.../opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1476, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!label3"
```

***Desired output***

for the answer_label to be removed if all entries are valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to remove the text of the label in the `try` block:

```
try:
    user_start_pw_num = float(start_pw.get())
    user_end_pw_num = float(end_pw.get())

    user_pw_range = [user_start_pw_num, user_end_pw_num ]
    print('user_pw_range: ',user_pw_range)

    answer_label.config(text='')

except ValueError:
    answer_label.config(text='You must enter an integer or decimal number', fg='red')
```

Merge the two `try`-`except` blocks into one.

Comment: Thank you pups, both ideas work perfectly, much appreciated.